# Deserializing many data classes from files as quickly as possible

Tags: python, concurrency, parallel-processing, python-dataclasses

I have a data class which represents some data on which I want to do some further processing. The data class was serialized into json files with `from_dict`. Looks something like this

```
class Currency:
    USD = "USD"
    EUR = "EUR"

@dataclass
class CurrencyPosition:
    currency: Currency
    balance: float

@dataclass
class StockPosition:
    ticker: str
    name: str
    balance: int

@dataclass
class Portfolio:
    currencies: List[CurrencyPosition]
    stocks: List[StockPosition]
   
    def to_dict(self) -> dict: 
         return {
             "currencies": [x.to_json() for x in self.currencies]
             "stocks": [x.to_json() for x in self.stocks]
         }

    @classmethod
    def from_dict(cls, data) -> "Portfolio":
        return cls(
            currencies=[CurrencyPosition.from_dict(x) for x in data["currencies"],
            stocks=[StockPositon.from_dict(x) for x in data["stocks"]
        )
```

Now I have a big directory of portfolios set up say something like this:

```
portfolios
├── portfolio_1.json
├── portfolio_2.json
├── .
├── .
├── .
└── portfolio_2000000.json
```

I want to read all the 2,000,000 portfolios into a list (generator ideally for memory purposes) as quickly as possible. I have tried using `joblib` multithreading and multiprocessing implementations and compared it to a serial implementation and I do not find a huge speed difference sadly, I get something 30 ± 5 portfolios / second for multi threading, multi processing, and serial. This would mean it would take around 18 hours to process 2,000,000 portfolios :(

Any ideas/suggestions on how I can speedup my workflow currently it just looks like this.

```
from joblib import delayed, Parallel
from pathlib import Path
from my_lib import Portfolio

def portfolio_from_path(path: Path) -> Portfolio:
    with open(str(path), "r") as f:
        data = json.load(f)
    return Portfolio.from_dict(data)

def serial(paths: List[Path]) -> List[Portfolio]:
    return [portfolio_from_path(x) for x in paths]

def multi_processing(paths: List[Path]) -> List[Portfolio]:
    with Parallel(n_jobs=-1) as parallel:
        results = parallel(delayed(portfolio_from_path)(x) for x in paths)
    return results

def multi_threading(paths: List[Path]) -> List[Portfolio]:
    # n_jobs from ThreadPoolExecutor min(32, (os.cpu_count() or 1) + 4)
    # 8 cores on my machine
    with Parallel(n_jobs=12, prefer="threads") as parallel:
        results = parallel(delayed(portfolio_from_path)(x) for x in paths)
    return results

if __name__ == "__main__":
    paths = list(Path("./portfolios").glob("*.json"))
    serialized_portfolios = multi_processing(paths)
```

Comment: Have you tried using Dask or Pyspark?

Comment: Are you sure that handling 2 million jsons is the best approach? A DBMS could perhaps be better here?

Comment: how's your `from_dict` defined for `CurrencyPosition` and other classes, etc.?

Comment: Id personally look into something like `serde` and rust because I heard that rust is really fast and might be a good fit for this kind of task actually.

Comment: Pretty much what you'd expect @rv.kvetch,  I pretty just return a dict containing currency and balance for `CurrencyPosition.to_dict`

Comment: Just tried Dask, seems to be pretty much the same speed as what I'm doing but I guess w/ less code: in any case Dask seems to be a good library for my use case. I guess I'm still confused as to why parallelization doesn't make a huge difference in terms of speed here.

Comment: please add the needed imports for this code to work.  `Parallel` shows there from nowhere.

Comment: Also, if you want help to run this as genrerator, add the code that invokes the functions that do the unserializing.  All we have here are functions that take lists and output lists, and the calling code have to be adapted as well.

Comment: what is `read_json`?

Comment: If I had to speculate, parallelization isn't making a huge difference because the main bottleneck is probably reading from disk, which if understand things correctly, is going to happen serially anyway.

Comment: And fundamentally, this is just not a great way to store lots of data. You should consider an alternative serialization format